# Passing value to controller action

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to pass two values to the following controller action using jQuery

```
[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult Cancel(Guid Id, string cancelReason)
        {
            //do something
        }
```

.js:

```
    CancelProgram = function (Id) {
//this is basically the value from a select tag placed on the form            
var reason = $("#CancelReasons").val();
            alert(reason);

            Origin.ajax({
                url: '/ZYX/Cancel?Id=' + Id,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: { cancelReason: reason },
                success: function (data) {
                    alert('success!');
                }
            });
        };
    });
```

The value of cancelReason in the action method is always null. Any pointers on why this is not working?

Comment: What's `Origin.ajax`? I see that your question is tagged with `jquery` but I am not aware of an `Origin` object. Is it something custom made? Or a third party framework or something?

Comment: Its a custom made object but behaves exactly like jQuery

Comment: I don't know if it behaves like jQuery. Because if it behaved like jQuery it would have worked. When you use `data: { id: '24fe0c97-c227-4312-91fc-6e651df8b64f', cancelReason: 'some reason' }` both values should be sent. Try hardcoding them as I have shown to ensure that there aren't some other side effects. Also use a javascript debugger tool such as FireBug. It allows you to analyze the exact requests/responses being sent. You will be able to see whether the AJAX request is valid or not.

Comment: I used firebug, and both id and cancelReason have the right values, but somehow, the controller is getting just the Id value.

Comment: that's impossible. See my answer for an example of how a successful AJAX request should look. Show us what you see in FireBug. We cannot read your mind. What I can tell you is that the code I have shown works. So if yours doesn't you will have to provide a way for us to reproduce your problem if you are unable to debug it yourself. You mentioned something about third party tools, we don't know what you mean. I have strictly no idea what Origin.ajax is. I know that `jQuery.ajax` works. So as I explained in my answer start by hardcoding the values and using the standard `jQuery.ajax` method.

Comment: Makes sense. Let me spend some more time on running it through FireBug and see what I can post here. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There must be something wrong with another part of your code. I would start by sending a normal AJAX request by hardcoding the values and ensuring that they are properly sent:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/ZYX/Cancel',
    type: 'POST',
    data: { 
        id: '24fe0c97-c227-4312-91fc-6e651df8b64f', 
        cancelReason: 'some reason' 
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert('success!');
    }
});
```

Once you ensure that this simple example works start making it more dynamic by using variables. This way you will be able to narrow down and find the origin of your problem. Also I would very strongly recommend you using a javascript debugging tool such as FireBug. It allows you to see in the Console whether you have javascript errors as well as many other useful information such as the exact requests/responses being sent.

In the case of a successful AJAX request here's what you should see in the Network Tab of FireBug:

```
Accept:             */*
Accept-Encoding:    gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:    en-us,en;q=0.5
Connection:         keep-alive
Content-Length:     64
Content-Type:       application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
User-Agent:         Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:10.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/10.0
X-Requested-With:   XMLHttpRequest

id=24fe0c97-c227-4312-91fc-6e651df8b64f&cancelReason=some+reason
```

Notice how both the `id` and the `cancelReason` parameters are sent using `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

You should really learn to debug those kind of problems and the way to debug them is by using the proper tools.

Comment: Ok. So I had to move both the Id and cancelReason into the "data" part and it started to work. I was under the impression that I can pass an extra value using the "data" without changing the call to the controller.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
            url: '/ZYX/Cancel',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { Id: Id, cancelReason: reason },
            success: function (data) {
                alert('success!');
            }
```

Comment: same thing. Id gets a value but cancelReason doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the route your specified and that might help answer a little better, however this should work for now:

```
url: '/ZYX/Cancel?Id=' + Id + '&cancelReason=' + reason,
```

And, do not pass any data in at all. If this does not work, then I would use fiddler or another network watcher add-on or debugger to verify that reason is a valid value.

Comment: Is it possible to not change the current route but pass and extra variable to the controller using the 'data' part of the jQuery?

Comment: @GoldenUser AFAIK, you either must have a route specified to handle this, or you must pass everything as a query parameter.

Answer (score -2):

Try setting up a route in your Global.asax file, something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "Cancel", // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}/{cancelReason}", // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "YourController", action = "Cancel", id = UrlParameter.Optional, cancelReason = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
        );
```

Comment: Is it possible to not change the current route but pass and extra variable to the controller using the 'data' part of the jQuery?